# Angular directive pass function / raise event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have been upgrading a legacy project to angular. Using the dhtmlxgrid I created a directive.

```
angular.module('amod', []).directive('dxGrid', function() {

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: false,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',

    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $controller) {

        $scope.$watch($attrs.data, function(xmlData) {
            mygrid.clearAll();
            mygrid.loadXMLString(xmlData); 
         mygrid
        });


        //init grid
        var mygrid = new dhtmlXGridObject($element[0]);


    }

  };
});
```

This works great for binding data but now I need to respond when the user row selected event

From the dhtmlxgrid doc.

```
   grid.attachEvent("onRowDblClicked", function(rId,cInd){

   });
```

In the end what I would like to do is run a function on the controller whenever a row is selected and also be able to pass in a row to the directive.

Comment: Since you're not using an isolate scope, you should be able to just call the controller function from your event handler: `$scope.controllerFunction(row)`. Regarding "also be able to pass in a row to the directive", you're going to need to clarify what you mean there, and that should probably be asked in a separate question.